# Where/how does the conversion of entity objects to data transfer objects take place in Clean Architecture?

Tags: database, clean-architecture, repository-pattern

Prolog:

I have a domain-layer which contains some entity-classes like `Customer`.

I have a application-layer which contains some data transfer object classes like `CustomerDto`.

My Problem:

At a presenter (in my presentation-layer) a use case interactor was called like `NewCustomerUseCaseInteractor.Execute(new NewCustomerUseCase("MyNewCustomer"))`.
These `execute()` method is implemented at the application layer and uses the entity classes like `Customer`. But the presenter get later a List of all customers as a `List(of CustomerDto)`.

**Question: Where/how does the conversion of entity objects (`Customer`) to data transfer objects (`CustomerDto`) take place in clean architecture?**

Comment: _"These execute method is implemented at the application layer and uses the entity classes"_ If your application layer is handling this so-called entity, then either it's not an entity or it already crossed a boundary that it shouldn't have. It's hard to distinguish between these two from the perspective of someone reading this question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a really hard time with the implementation. Maybe I'm throwing everything out the window. Regarding your comment: The `execute()` method creates a new instance of `Customer` and adds it to the `DomainEventRepository`. (When `Customer` is created, then a `new CustomerCreatedEvent(..)` is also created. But that is a whole other (more difficult) site again).

My approach now is, that where the evaluation of these `DomainEvents` happens, not the domain entities (`Customer`) but the data transfer objects (`CustomerDto`) are worked with.

Comment: Do you know what's a DTO for? Because they fulfil a purpose that can take place anywhere in the code. Controllers  (in the application layer) use to be a common one, but it's not the only one. Class mapping is a cross-cutting concern, it doesn't belongs to any layer in particular.

Comment: I know and you are right (only I think, that the DTOs are not in the Domainlayer). But the question is:  when/where will be a converting from domain-entity to adata-entity done? The mapper will it do, also right. But when (on the dataflow) will this happen? By executing in the usecase-handler?By executing in the domainevent-handler?

Comment: @Cit Your last comment clears up my confusion. "Entity" is generally interpreted to be the PERSISTENCE entity, i.e. the class that is private to the persistence layer.